# How to copy to clipboard from a input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a website in html, php, javascript, etc. In that I want to add a specific button, after button clicked the words from input box should get copied into clipboard. I have tried by using Zeroclipboard but I could not.

I have used the following code and added `jquery.zclip.js` and `jquery-1.8.0.min.js` to the same directory. Welcome for any suggestions.

```
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="jquery.zclip.js"></script> 
    <style> 
        #dynamic { font-size: 15px; height: 28px; width: 357px; } 
    </style> 
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("a#copy-dynamic").zclip({ 
                      path:"ZeroClipboard.swf", 
                      copy:function(){return $("input#dynamic").val();} 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
<body> 
    <input type="text" id="dynamic" value="Copy me !!" /> 
    <a href="#copy" id="copy-dynamic">Copy Now</a> 
</body>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.zclip.js"></script>

<style>
#dynamic {
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 28px;
    width: 357px;
}
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a#copy-dynamic").zclip({
           path:"ZeroClipboard.swf",
           copy:function(){return $("input#dynamic").val();}
        });
    });
</script> 

</head>

  <body>
      <input type="text" id="dynamic" value="Copy me !!" />
      <a href="#copy" id="copy-dynamic">Copy Now</a>
  </body>

Comment: Please edit your question and don't post code as a comment.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript.

Comment: @evolutionxbox not quite. OP is using a flash script that has the access of the computers clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to deal with ZeroClipboard; the docs are not the greatest.

First you need to add the source script to the head of your html document:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.2.0/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
```

I used a CDN, but I'm sure it works fine if you have a local copy.

Then in your javascript, in global scope:

```
ZeroClipboard.config( { swfPath: "whateverpath/ZeroClipboard.swf" } );
```

Then you need to bind the swf to the element you want to use to trigger copying:

```
var copyButton = document.getElementById('thingThatCopies');
var copyclient = new ZeroClipboard(copyButton); //can be array
```

It should work from there, but in case you want to add a user notification, there are some events you can work with:

```
copyclient.on("ready", function(readyEvent) {
    //is ready
    copyclient.setText(window.location.href);
    //in this instance, set the text to copy to the url of the current page. You can set it to anything with this function
    copyclient.on("aftercopy", function(event) {
        //copied
        //this is the place to add a user notification
    }
}
```

Hopefully that gives you enough of a start to adapt it to your project.